# Javax.Mail trying to use gmail's imap extension to access X-GM-MSGID

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-imap

I'm trying to use the `X-GM-EXT-1` IMAP extension created by google for gmail in javax.mail.  Doc here https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions

I'm specifically trying to fetch a sequence of `X-GM-MSGID` headers using the `UID FETCH` syntax extension.

The java code I'm using:
(I'm using real uids in my command, but for the sake of example, I'm pasting the same range from the doc's example)

```
Response[] r = (Response[]) folder.doCommand(protocol -> protocol.command("UID FETCH 1:4 (X-GM-MSGID)", null));
```

This way of declaring an imap command has worked for me for other extensions (ESEARCH specifically)

This is a snippet from the docs which is the source material I'm basing my experiment on.

```
a008 FETCH 1:4 (X-GM-THRID)
* 1 FETCH (X-GM-THRID 1278455344230334865)
* 2 FETCH (X-GM-THRID 1266894439832287888) 
* 3 FETCH (X-GM-THRID 1266894439832287888)
* 4 FETCH (X-GM-THRID 1266894439832287888)
a008 OK FETCH (Success)
```

I'm expecting my `Response[]` object to contain multiple response lines, one for each of the fetched messages, and then the tagged `OK FETCH (Success)` line.  However, I'm only getting one line in my response that is `A57 OK Success`.  I'm unsure what this means, maybe javax.mail isn't doing something as I expect under the hood, or maybe something specific needs to be done to access the full response.

Is there a better way, or more correct way to go about using this extension?

Edit:

Here is an executable example, this printed to the console the output I described.  One requirement is that the gmail inbox that is authenticated with the imap store that needs to be passed in must have at least 1 message in the folder so that ESEARCH is able to identify a MIN uid to use.

```
private void MCVE(IMAPStore store) throws MessagingException {
    IMAPFolder inbox = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("Inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY, ResyncData.CONDSTORE);

    Response[] minUidResponse = (Response[]) inbox.doCommand(
            protocol -> protocol.command("UID SEARCH RETURN (min max count all) 1:*", null)
    );

    String minUid = "";
    for (Response aLine : minUidResponse) {
        String str = aLine.toString();
        if (str.startsWith("* ESEARCH")) {
            List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList(str.split(" "));
            minUid = tokens.get(tokens.indexOf("MIN") + 1);
        }
    }

    final String finalMinUid = minUid; // lambas need effectively final stuff
    Response[] gidResponse = (Response[]) inbox.doCommand(
            protocol -> protocol.command("UID FETCH " + finalMinUid + " (X-GM-MSGID)", null)
    );

    System.out.println("Printing result of X-GM-MSGID uid fetch");
    for (Response r : gidResponse) {
        System.out.println(r.toString());
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

After enabling debug mode in the mail session, I see that an exception is being thrown and hidden from regular output.

```
 DEBUG IMAP: connection available -- size: 1
 A4 ENABLE CONDSTORE
 * ENABLED
 A4 OK Success
 A5 EXAMINE Inbox (CONDSTORE)
 * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing)
 * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Flags permitted.
 * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1] UIDs valid.
 * 7 EXISTS
 * 0 RECENT
 * OK [UIDNEXT 23071] Predicted next UID.
 * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 1327692]
 A5 OK [READ-ONLY] Inbox selected. (Success)
 A6 UID SEARCH RETURN (min max count all) 1:*
 * ESEARCH (TAG "A6") UID COUNT 7 MIN 23064 MAX 23070 ALL 23064:23070
 A6 OK SEARCH completed (Success)
 A7 UID FETCH 23064 (X-GM-MSGID)
 * 1 FETCH (X-GM-MSGID 1594485864262816838 UID 23064 MODSEQ (1327330))
 DEBUG IMAP: ignoring bad response, THROW:
 com.sun.mail.iap.ParsingException: error in FETCH parsing, unrecognized item at index 11, starts with "X-GM-MSGID 159448586..."
     at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FetchResponse.parse(FetchResponse.java:219)
     at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FetchResponse.<init>(FetchResponse.java:96)
     at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:392)
     at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.command(Protocol.java:354)
     at my.package.ImapSync.lambda$MCVE$5(ImapSync.java:85)
     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.doProtocolCommand(IMAPFolder.java:3784)
     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.doCommand(IMAPFolder.java:3734)
     at my.package.ImapSync.MCVE(ImapSync.java:84)
     ...
 A7 OK Success


 Printing result of X-GM-MSGID uid fetch
 A7 OK Success
```

Edit 3:

The version of javamail I'm using is 1.5.5.  I'm going to attempt to upgrade to 1.6.1 to see if that changes anything with how the server response is parsed.

A quick test of the same example code after upgrading to 1.6.1 still had the same result.  So this isn't something that has been "fixed" with time.  (Quotes because I don't know if javamail has a bug, or if I'm misusing it)

Comment: Can you provide an MCVE?

Comment: @Max I'll work on making one.

Comment: @Max Just pinging you to let you know I added an example that demonstrates the output I'm getting

Comment: Great, and can you turn on protocol debugging and show the trace? (https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug)

Comment: @Max That was a good idea, it did reveal some new stuff even if I'm not fully sure what to make of it yet.  I attached it to the bottom of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it the hard way.  Just use the ["gimap" protocol provider for JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/package-summary.html).

Comment: I didn't realize this existed.  Thanks, I'll try it out tomorrow

Comment: After adding that jar to my project, I had to change my protocol to `"gimap"` to get the correct store, and change all the properties passed in from `mail.imap.xxx` to `mail.gimap.xxx`.  With those changes, I'm able to cast my folder and message instances to the Gmail variants and access those gmail specific attributes.  Thanks again

Comment: According to the javadoc, this feature is experimental. Bill, would you advise to use it also in production? Also, it looks like it's using XLIST, which has been [deprecated by Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions#xlist_is_deprecated). (Bill, thanks a lot for JavaMail: amazing library :-) )

Comment: It hasn't been using XLIST since 2013.  The "experimental" warning is to make it clear that the API is not defined by any standard and might change from release to release, causing you to need to rewrite your code if you upgrade to a newer release.  None of that is planned, but it's a risk you need to consider.  And as you saw with XLIST, Gmail's IMAP protocol extensions aren't exactly stable either.